# Remember Password(caching password) using Jgit

Tags: java, authentication, jgit

I am using jgit in my spring boot application for git integration,
I wanted to make my application to ask git username and password for only one time,
Can anyone give me some idea how to achieve it
(**Note:Due to security reason we are not supposed to store password in Database**)
Is there any method available in jgit to achieve it or suggest any other way.

Thanks in advance